# set texture of a sprite is not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am trying to set texture with this :

```
[[self setSpriteByTag] setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0001.png",face]]];
```

when `[self setSpriteByTag]` return a sprite `face` is an image string, and they both ok because i have logged them.

this sprite is a child of a page in `ccscrolayer` :
one page of the layer pages :

```
 CCLayer *page1 = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
        BACK.position=ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2);
         [page1 addChild:BACK];
```

when i was trying to change `BACK`'s image , with the command i wrote here.
what happen is that i see a white screen.
i have check that the image is in my assets .

what could be the problem ?
the facr that i change a sprite that is a child of a page ?

**edit :**

this is the function that gives me the sprite BACK:

```
-(CCSprite*)setSpriteByTag 
{

     int currentPage=[scroller currentScreen];
     [globals sharedGlobals].currentPageG=currentPage; //move to touch ended?
     currentPage=currentPage+1;
     //NSLog(@"PAGE:%d",currentPage);



    if(currentPage==1)
    {[globals sharedGlobals].WhatFace =@"BeastFace";  return  BACK;} 
    else if(currentPage==2)
    {[globals sharedGlobals].WhatFace =@"BlueFace"; return BACK1;}
    else if(currentPage==3)
```

Comment: What is Back? Please elaborate the structure of the code properly.. You question will be solved in minutes.. M not able to understand what you want to do.. I hav done it many a hundred times..

Comment: @ Nikhil Aneja back is a sprite i wrote that, it loaded to a page of a scroller, and has initial image, which i want to change .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets white only in case when image is not present in the resources.. I checked running same code.. It works fine.. If I put wrong name of the image which is not present.. It changes to white... Please check for the image

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0001.png",face]
```

M sure problem is in the image name.. :)

Comment: the image is there. for sure ! i have tried many many images, i have log the command you wrote here, the image is good. have you tried it with a scroller? i am changing a scroller. see my edit please.

Comment: This sprite is a child of a layer .. that is a part of CCScrollerLayer.. ?? Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0001.png",face]
```

Your filenames will have to have the format "xxxxx0001.png". Assuming the face variable is the string "BeastFace" then the filename to load will be "BeastFace0001.png".

So far the obvious but keep in mind that the file "Beastface0001.png" will not load on the device, and neither will "beastface0001.png" because iOS devices use a case-sensitive file system. It will work on the iOS Simulator though.